# Install Ubuntu in dual boot on an encrypted partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem, encryption, truecrypt

I'm totally new to Linux and I'm trying to achieve something, but I don't know if my plans are okay.

I would like to have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu in dual boot. Windows is on my RAIDed SSDs, and I would like to have Ubuntu installed on a partition on my 1TB HDD. That partition (~330GB) would be fully encrypted with TrueCrypt, and I would use Ubuntu on it to run VirtualBox mainly. The other partition on the HDD would serve as storage only.

About the File Systems, better go with ext3, ext4, XFS, another one? I'd want Ubuntu to be bootable obviously.
 And also, would that be okay if the Ubuntu partition was ext3/ext4/XFS/something else (and fully encrypted) **and** if at the same time the other partition on the same HDD ( for storage ) was NTFS?

For a start, should I first install Ubuntu and then encrypt, or first encrypt the partition and then install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: stick to the default of ext4, unless you know why you want something different. The Ubuntu installer offers the option to encrypt your partition for you using LUKS, however if you wish to use TrueCrypt then you should encrypt the partition before you install! Note that TrueCrypt is no longer being developed and it is uncertain if it is still safe. TrueCrypt has been forked under the name of [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/). Ubuntu can read NTFS so that should be fine. Windows however can't read ext4 without third party drivers and therefore can't read your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: @karel At the risk of going off topic, you might want to have a look at CipherShed too https://ciphershed.org/ which is also a fork of TrueCrypt, but one that is trying to stick to the old truecrypt volumes. Although I tought the latest version of Veracrypt could do the newer volumes too, where did you read that Veracrypt doesn't read Truecrypt 7.x volumes?

Comment: [VeraCrypt Now Supports Mounting & Converting TrueCrypt Volumes](http://www.davescomputertips.com/veracrypt-now-supports-mounting-converting-truecrypt-volumes/) -- I was wrong, the latest version of VeraCrypt *does* support mounting and converting of TrueCrypt volumes, apparently the TrueCrypt 6.0 feature was added after that for backwards compatibility with volumes created by older versions of TrueCrypt.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have windows running in a virtual box inside ubuntu, did I get that right?
If yes I think its not the most secure way!
Having a "normal" dual boot should be more secure, as you have always just one encrypted volume decrypted!
Meaning:
If you have your encrypted ubuntu booted and then start Windows in the VirtualBox, you have both encryption phrases temporarily in your RAM at the same time. Normally a naughty Windows virus/trojan etc should not be able to access you Ubuntu outside the VirtualBox, but I guess it's still saver to just have a normal dual boot. Besides having just the encryption passphrases loaded you need atm you will also have great speed benefits in Windows!
VeraCrypt fully supports this, there are some tutorials on the net, or just ask if there are problems.

PS: This is just a personal view and might be total wrong.